# Why is Python Shell printing out <<function Josh at 0x029E34F8>?

Tags: python

[image]

Just wondering if there is something wrong with my code? I am trying to create a Pig game, and shell looks like a mess because of this long number.

Comment: Please paste that code in your question.

Comment: Not a screenshot please

Comment: See: [Why may I not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `print(Josh, …)` in your code.  This doesn't call the function (not sure whether this was your intention), but instead passes the function object to the print function, so you are effectively asking Python to print a function object.  Python does this by printing the name and the address of the function.

If you actually want to call the function, you the function call operator `()`.  If you want to return a value from the function, use the `return` statement.

Comment: Thank you Sven! https://i.gyazo.com/cdbae12141fddb9fd5c4c019b3236e9e.png